# Is thenable chaining asynchronous - Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

How is `thenable` chaining asynchrounous? It looks like the `promise` returned from the previous `Promise.then` is blocking (The intention itself is to block as per the example given below) the next `Promise.then` in the chain . I am new to the `promises` in Node.js. Can anyone please help me understand better how `thenable` chaining is asynchronous? 
From the given example, why don't we use synchronous functions themselves instead of using `thenable` chains?

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) { // (***)

  alert(result); // 2
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4
  return result * 2;

});
```

Comment: What do you mean "blocking"?

Comment: Each promise is async, but by chaining them together, the next promise will not be executed until the previous one completes. The difference is though, by being async, they're not blocking the UI thread, and other code outside of the then chain can still execute

Comment: Not sure what other behaviour you could expect. The `then` callback of course can only run after you (asynchronously, in the `setTimeout`) `resolve`d the promise, that's the whole purpose (and it's impossible to get the `result` of `1` before that call happened).

Answer (score 4):

A `then` chain is asynchronous in the sense that the code following a promise chain will be executed without waiting for the promise to reach its resolved state.

```
function sleep (ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve, setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// counts to 3 in 3 seconds, thanks to asynchronicity
sleep(3000).then(() => console.log('3'));
sleep(2000).then(() => console.log('2'));
sleep(1000).then(() => console.log('1'));
```

The `then` method of a given promise provides a way to attach any function
that should wait for its return value (*). 
A promise chain thus represents a "synchronous sequence of instructions"
but it is asynchronous with respect to the rest of the program.

```
function add (i) {
    return sleep(1000)
        .then(() => { console.log(i+1); return i+1 });
}

// counts to 3 in 3 seconds, thanks to synchronicity along the chain
Promise.resolve(0).then(add).then(add).then(add);
```

Of course introducing asynchronicity would be completely useless if one had only to deal with linear chains. 
Relevance only appears when creating parallel chains. In contrast, take this simple synchronous shell script:

```
// counts *down* in 6 seconds
sleep 3; echo 3;
sleep 2; echo 2;
sleep 1; echo 1;
```

Observe that sleeping typically represents waiting for some varied resources over the network to get a clear sense of the benefits of asynchronicity.

In the meantime, asynchronicity would be impossible to deal with in the absence of a convenient way to linearise tasks and have some pieces of code wait for one another. 
Promises are a convenient way to achieve this, between the past "callback pyramid of doom" and the ECMA 2017 async/await keywords to come, [see here](https://blog.hellojs.org/asynchronous-javascript-from-callback-hell-to-async-and-await-9b9ceb63c8e8) for example.

(*) Be careful to always return something in intermediate functions,
otherwise the whole rest of the chain may stop waiting.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not blocking the `then()` call. All the `then()` calls happen immediately after you created the promise, and the code continues to run synchronously.

It's only that `then` *callbacks* that will get deferred asynchronously until the promise was resolved. And each `then()` call returns a new promise for the result of the callback, so that you can chain them together and each callback will get called after the other.

But there's no blocking:

```
console.log("creating the first promise");
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("starting the timeout")
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("resolving the first promise");
        resolve(1);
    }, 1000);
});
console.log("installing the callback");
var nextPromise = promise.then(function(result) {
    console.log("receiving the result", result);
    return result * 2;
});
console.log("continuing synchronously after the then() call");

// and so on with
// nextPromise.then(nextResult => console.log("receiving second result", result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer that *why* question. If you consider your code then it doesn't really matter, you could do just fine without promises. Like this.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  let result = 1;
  alert(result);
  result *= 2;
  alert(result);
  result *= 2;
  alert(result);
  result *= 2;
}, 1000);
```

But that is because, aparat from `setTimeout`, the code is synchronous. But imagine if you wanted to chain asynchronous functions without promises. You can still do it, but it leads to rather convoluted, hard to read code (callback hell).

Let's see how your code would look like in such case.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  let result = 1;
  alert(result);

  setTimeout((function(result) {
    result *= 2;
    alert(result);

    setTimeout((function(result) {
      result *= 2;
      alert(result);
    }).bind(null, result), 0);
  }).bind(null, result), 0);
}, 1000);
```

It still does the same, but it looks much worse than the code using promises. (And imagine how it would look like if you wanted to chain more, let's say 10, functions like this)